# Can start a sentence using the conjunction or?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I'm doing this essay that's due in a week and I'm a little stuck. It's a compare and contrast essay and I'm starting a sentence using the conjunction or. Can you do that or do you a have to use another word/phrase?

Comment: What's the context? Can you tell us the sentence in question and the sentence before it?

Comment: Or you give a context or the question is unanswerable :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are circumstances when it is appropriate to start a sentence with a conjunction.  So long as the sentence is not the entirety of a work, you have appropriate context from either the prior paragraph or from the prior sentence within the same paragraph.  Or you could invoke artistic license, and abandon the context altogether.

---

Mind, just because usual english language practice allows a thing when appropriate does not necessarily mean that your usage is appropriate, or that the practice is even allowed in your particular assignment.  Since you have a week, write the essay as you have it now, and **ask whomever you're writing it for** if they have any specific rules.

Even if you're not in school, the house style may trump what you're writing for a reference manual, newspaper, or whatever.